# C++ use of strings

Tags: c++, string, function

I am new to c++ programming I have an assignment the takes the content of a txt file and checks the content with a dictionary txt file. When I send the string[] to my function I always get an error which states that the std::basic string can not be converted to std::strin

```
    ifstream d_file("dictionary.txt");
    string l;
    vector<string> user_vec;

    while( getline( d_file, l ) ) {
        user_vec.push_back( l);
    }

    size_t line_count = user_vec.size();

    for( size_t i = 0; i < line_count; ++i )
    {
        // cout << i << "    " << user_vec[i] << endl;
        bool result =  inDictionary(word, user_vec[i]);

    }



}

bool inDictionary(string word,string dictionary[])
{
    cout<<word<< dictionary<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in a string the function is expecting a string array.

Change `inDictionary` to the following since `user_vec[i]` is a string.

```
bool inDictionary(string& word,string& dictionary)
{
    cout<<word<< dictionary<<endl;
}
```

Or if you want to pass in all the lines into the `inDictionary` function pass the vector into the function.

```
bool inDictionary(string& word, std::vector<string>& dictionary)
{
   //...
}
```

Then you would pass the vector like `bool result = inDictionary(word, user_vec);`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`user_vec[i]`is a string;
`string dictionary[]` is string array, type mismatch.

You have to change the prototype of the `inDictionary` function.